# How severe would the consequences be if the earth's moon were wrenched from orbit?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, moon

The old TV series [Space 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space:_1999) from the early 1970s seems to have resurfaced on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6BXaGEuqxo&frags=pl%2Cwn) reminding me of something I watched as a child.

It is one of those obviously ridiculous SciFi series (from the team that also did things like Thunderbirds and Captain Scarlett). So we don't really expect to take it seriously.

The key premise of the series is that the moon (and the people working on the human moonrise) are cast adrift from earth when a huge explosion in a nuclear dump blows the moon out of earth's orbit.

OK this is a ridiculous idea. But how ridiculous? Ignoring the problem of anything having enough energy to achieve the feat, what would be the realistic consequences of such an event for the moon or the earth (assuming it could happen quickly)? Could either planet survive?

Comment: Overwhelming catastrophe? The binding energy and rotational momentum of the Earth-Moon system is vast and something powerful enough to disrupt it would probably change the length of the day and cause catastrophic tidal flooding at the minimum.

Comment: https://www.popsci.com/what-would-happen-if-moon-suddenly-disappeared#page-3